# Looking for way to set searchbox text to "Search blah..." that disappears like listview "filter items"

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a seachbox the I'd like to populate with some text.  i.e. "Search for xxxxx" that behaves like a listview : it disappears when you type in the box.

Is this possible for a input type=searchbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using something like this [jQuery-watermark plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) that you simply include as a script in your page, then you can set the watermark using:

```
$('#inputId').watermark('Required information');
```